# create image in React from backend dataURL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, axios, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get a snapshot of HTML canvas like so:

```
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    let image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    await axios.post('/api/entries/', { dataURL: image })
```

which seems to be working, and connected properly to the database.

But I can't figure out how to use the dataURL to create an image component on the React frontend

I'm able to fetch them from the backend just fine and log the dataURL.

```
    const pics = await axios.get('/api/entries/')
    pics.data.map((pic) => { console.log(pic.dataURL) })
```

I guess I'm just not sure of the next steps to get each dataURL into a  element

Here is my getPics function:

```
  const getPics = async () => {
    const pics = await axios.get('/api/entries/')

    return (
      pics.data.map((pic) => (
        <img src={pic.dataURL} key={pic.dataURL} />
      ))
    )
  }
```

and its used just like:

```
<div>
  {getPics()}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the images into a state and put the fetch into a `useEffect()` function.

```jsx
const [pic,setPics] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const getPics = async () => await axios.get('/api/entries/')
    .then(res => {
    setPics(res.data);
    })
  getPics();
}, [])
```

Mapping is the correct way to go... when mapping you can throw the data into a img element, this will render every image onto the page. the key value is for react to know the difference between each element.

```jsx
return (
  {pics.data.map((pic) => (
    <img src={pic.dataURL} key={pic.dataURL} />
  ))}
)
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, I just have a simple div with `{getPics()}` inside which has your response, but it returns the error:  Objects are not valid as a React child. 

I edited my question to show the function

Comment: i edited my answer by putting the images into a state instead of just a constant. when getting a api response, the objects are not default to go into the ui, putting into a state will make these objects displayable.

Comment: Think it's close, but I'm getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')`

using `{pics.data.map((pic) => (<img src={pic.dataURL} key={pic._id} />))}`

I should mention though, that if I make a button to just `console.log(pics.data);` it works perfectly.

Comment: So everything seems to be working now, but only if I render the pictures using a button like onClick = showPics, otherwise if I try to render them on page reload, there is no data. I guess it's trying to render the pictures before setState happens, anything I can do about this race condition? - for now I just have a loading state, and after the getPics function I set it to false, which renders the pictures, is there a better way? Marking your answer as correct though, as its helped me a ton.

Comment: i switched `setPics(res)` to `setPics(res.data)` because the full result return comes each object as `res.data.data[#].dataURL` lmk if that works

Comment: @Grambam did you include the **useEffect()** function?

Comment: I did set up the getPics in useEffect yeah :)

Comment: you marked it as the answer... did you get it to display on render?

Comment: I did, I just added `const [picsLoaded, setPicsLoaded] = useState(false);`

and set it to true, after your useEffect function. Works perfectly, but I'm wondering if its the best way.